# uwp app will be terminated when it's in suspending state

Tags: uwp

I followed the [official CameraGetPreviewFrame code sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/CameraGetPreviewFrame) to make my own camera functions, but when my app triggered the suspending event, the `mediaCapture.StopPreviewAsync` method will wait for a long time, then the app will be terminated by system.

You could use the above CameraGetPreviewFrame code sample to reproduce this issue.

```
private async void Application_Suspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
        {
            // Handle global application events only if this page is active
            if (Frame.CurrentSourcePageType == typeof(MainPage))
            {
                var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();

                await CleanupCameraAsync();

                await CleanupUiAsync();

                deferral.Complete();
            }
        }
```

How to resolve it?

Comment: Did any unhandled exception occur during the test?